# Enable to post simple text twit using FHSTwitterEngine in IOS

Tags: ios, twitter

My application having twitter login and post  twit on twitter. so i am using **FHSTwitterEngine** github demo.
i am successfully login using **FHSTwitterEngine**. But facing problem to twit post on twitter.
At the time of twit , i am getting this error in my device  “**Twitter NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012**”.
Ao pls any one can give me solution for twit post using **FHSTwitterEngine**
And original demo is also not working for me in my device. original demo also give same error “**Twitter NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012**” 
Link of github demo : “**https://github.com/alvani/FHSTwitterEngine**”

Comment: Please describe your question more briefly......

Comment: Hey @Ghandhyam Tomar  : Now, can u got my Problem?

Answer (score 0):

Error code -1012 is kCFURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication. This should mean that some code somewhere called [sender cancelAuthenticationChallenge:] in response to an authentication challenge. This is likely code inside of **DMTwitterOAuth**, but it's also possible it's Apple's own code inside the URL-loading system. If you're trying to post a tweet you'll likely need Read and Write access.

Comment: but i am using FHSTwitterEngine  not using DMTwitterOAuth :(
give me solution for FHSTwitterEngine

Comment: https://twittercommunity.com/t/api-requests-with-twrequest-return-authentication-error/5735

https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine/issues/19
in above links might you'll found your solution.